# recode variable in loop R

Tags: r

im trying to recode a lot of variables (more than 53) in a loop, but it won't work. can someone please tell me, where my mistake is?

i give you a small exaple

```
data <-  read.csv("test.csv", header = TRUE, ";", na = -77)

data$var1 <- recode(data$var1, "1=0; 2=1; 3=2; 4=3; NA=NA")
```

here i have var 1-59 and several items that must be recoded in a different way.

i tried

```
for (i in 1:59){
get(paste0(data$var",i)) <- recode(paste0("data$var",i), "1=0; 2=1; 3=2; 4=3; NA=NA"
}
```

and

```
for (i in c(65, 73, 99){
get(paste0(data$var",i)) <- recode(paste0("data$var",i), "1=0; 2=0; 3=0; 4=1; NA=NA"
}
```

The Code will not work. Wheres my mistake? Can someone please give me a hind?

Thank you very much :)
derlu

Comment: I think you need `data[["paste0("var", i)]] <- recode(data[[paste0("var", i)]], ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a more readable `tidyverse` solution?

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

data %<>% 
  mutate_at(c(1:59)    , recode, '1'='0', '2'='1', '3'='2', '4'='3') %>%
  mutate_at(c(65,73,99), recode, '1'='0', '2'='0', '3'='0', '4'='1')
```

If you prefer, you can also use character vectors as the first argument that you pass to `mutate_at`. Like so:

```
data %<>% 
  mutate_at(paste0('var', c(1:59))    , recode, '1'='0', '2'='1', '3'='2', '4'='3') %>%
  mutate_at(paste0('var', c(65,73,99)), recode, '1'='0', '2'='0', '3'='0', '4'='1')
```

The third option (not applicable in this case because there are too many columns) is to use `vars`:

```
data %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(var65, var73, var99), recode, '1'='0', '2'='0', '3'='0', '4'='1')
```

Comment: Seems very Interesting. But where do i define the Variable that Must be recoded? Cant See It in the Code.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I just edited the answer to include referring to the variables by name, not only by position.

Comment: This way i recode the 1st to 59th item of my dataset (that includes 397 items). But i want to recode the items var1:var59

Comment: Thank you. This is what i needed. Cool.

Comment: it works fine for some items. for other get the message:

_Error in UseMethod("recode") : 
  no applicable method for 'recode' applied to an object of class "logical"_

Comment: Is It an issue with the missing values or the not recoded values (value 5 should not be recoded)

Comment: Yes, that issue happens sometimes when a column only contains NAs in and therefore defaults to logical. Is your problem solved now?

Comment: Im using It in a shiny Environment. Therefore i don’t get Outputs

Comment: Are there any NA-only columns in your dataset and if so, do you still want to include them? Did you try coercing them to factors?

Comment: Yes there are NA-only columns in the dataset. I have to include them.

Comment: What do you mean with coercing? No i havnt

Comment: I mean to convert them to factors, for example by running `mutate_at(c(1:59, 65,73,99), as.factor)` before the other `mutate_at` statements

Comment: I will try It and give you an Update

Comment: with converting them to factors resolves the problem. but now i cant do my normal statistical computations

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switch` function to recode values and `data.table` to recode values in all columns in one go:

```
library(data.table)    

# function to recode values
myfun <- function(val){
    if(is.na(val)) return (NA)
    else switch(val, '1'= '0','2' = '1', '3'='2','4'='3')
}

# apply the function to the selected columns
col_names <- paste0('var', 1:59)
df[,(col_names) := lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(sapply(x, myfun)) ), .SDcols = col_names]

print(df)
```

Comment: me understand, Where the Profit is towards the example above? The Code seems much more complicated :)

Comment: Sorry. Advantage.

Comment: The advantage is this code is fast and it avoids using nested for loop. It is easier to learn: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started